# Parallax effect in SwiftUI is offsetting images in list rows

Tags: swift, swiftui, parallax

I am learning to use parallax effect in SwiftUI. I got it working for my images in my list view. The only issue I am seeing with it is that it offsets the images the more list rows I have, as if the lower the rows are the lower the images are offset. I added a blue border for visual troubleshooting. I can only think of I am setting the calculation to the whole code. How would I ensure that the parallax is applied to every list row image individually without the image overflowing?

[image]

```
struct PostView: View {
    var post: sometest

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    // Parallax Effect for Display Image
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        let minY = geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.named("ScrollViewSpace")).minY
                        let parallaxOffset = minY * 0.1 // Adjust this factor for parallax intensity
                        
                        displayImageView(for: post)
                        //.resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .offset(y: parallaxOffset)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    
                    .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 0)
                    .clipped() 
                    .padding(.leading, -8)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried adding `minY` and `maxHeight` to explicitly declared as CGFloat. That fixed the images from bleeding but prevented parallax from working.

```
let parallaxOffset = min(max(minY, -maxHeight / 2), maxHeight / 2) * 0.2
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Based on your code, you offset images based on how far away they are from the top of, I would assume a `ScrollView` so they move as you scroll. It's not entirely clear to be what effect you are trying to achieve though. Should there be a "current" element where image is centered and other ones are not quite centered?

Comment: @Baglan I use `.coordinateSpace(name: "ScrollViewSpace")` in my `list` .  With that you mentioned I offset the images from top, I was trying to achieve to have their own offset in each list row so they move slightly as I scroll the list without bleeding out.

Comment: I see. For that, I think, you would want to know the "primary" position of that particular cell and calculate the offset of the cell from that position. By "primary", I mean a location of the cell when it's, for instance, at the center of the visible area. If you don't have to support previous versions of iOS, there are very useful enhancements to ScrollViews in iOS17, I suggest you to watch WWDC2023 videos about ScrollViews.

Comment: If you can't do that or want to "roll it yourself", you would need to decide on the "prime" location where the parallax effect would be zero. The center of the container might be the most natural place for that, if of, you would also need to know the height of the container. Here's a quick experiment: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/03b05ab54291a4e9ced1f6443168d1a6 let me know if that is something akin to what you were trying to do.

Comment: yea I did solve the issue few days ago, I used the effect in the center of the screen and I limited how much the image will move and it worked, but the more list rows I added the worse the graphical performance was, so I decided to stop using it. So thank you for all the help and ideas @Baglan